# Replace custom logo with text

Tags: theme-development

I have a WordPress website where I have no logo to use and I need to display text instead.

In my custom theme I've added support for a custom logo, but I have no idea of how to display custom text instead of a logo. Is there any function to do this?

Here is the header code I'm using:

```
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top shadow-lg" id="bs-nav">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="z-index:4;">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
<!-- Here i need to show the text -->
        <?php $logo = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_theme_mod('custom_logo'), 'full' ); ?>
          <img src="<?php echo $logo[0]; ?>" id="" width="80" height="80">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 float-right">
          <button class="hamburger hamburger--spin" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-content" aria-controls="navbar-content" aria-expand="false" aria-label="<?php _e('Toggle Navigation'); ?>">
            <span class="hamburger-box">
            <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
            </span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-content">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
              <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
                    'menu'           => 'Menu',
                    'container'      => false,
                    'depth'          => 2,
                    'menu_class'     => 'navbar-nav ml-auto',
                    'walker'         => new Bootstrap_NavWalker(),
                    'fallback_cb'    => 'Bootstrap_NavWalker::fallback',
                ) );
              ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the text which you input from Appearance > Customize > Site Identity you can use this code:

```
<h1><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel='home'><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
```

Otherwise, tell us from where that text should be coming from.

**You may also try the following:**

Open functions.php of your theme and add this:

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
    'height'      => 100,
    'width'       => 400,
    'flex-height' => true,
    'flex-width'  => true,
    'header-text' => array( 'site-title', 'site-description' ),
) );
```

Then add the following code wherever you want your logo to appear:

```
<?php 
   $custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
   $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $custom_logo_id , 'full' );
      ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="">
```

Then add your logo text inside of Appearance > Customize > Site Identity as shown here:
[image]

Comment: I will try with the first code solution you've posted. I already have the possibility to add a custom logo, so the text that is used for the site name will fit my needs. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. If the solution helps you please upvote the solution.